# I'm searching for graphic that displays all SharePoint 2013 sections

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Is there graphic or pdf that will display all of the sections of SharePoint 2013's interface. Does anyone know if there is such a thing?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Like this?  It is from Custom Guide of which I am not affiliated.  It is a one-pager on SharePoint 2013.
http://www.customguide.com/cheat_sheets/sharepoint-2013-quick-reference.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for graphic of Content Placeholders of Master page in Sharepoint 2013 then here is the [link](https://buli.waw.pl/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/sharepoint-2013-content-placeholders-seattle-master-page.png).

More details on this [link](https://buli.waw.pl/sharepoint-2013-content-placeholders-seattle-master/)